# Use Sencha GXT components within Vaadin

Tags: gwt, vaadin, gxt

I'm looking to use Sencha (GXT 3.0.1) components with Vaadin (version 7.1.8).

Anyone experienced with this integration than can provide some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i havent seen any integration, its hard to integrate. i used gxt and vaadin. please read vaadin docs. 2 frameworks are different in mind.

if you have so much free time. you can implement. You should write for all components server - client integration classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and Works.
Technically GXT component can be taken as a GWT widget. So, You can do it.
https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/105213